# In btrfs-check, how to automatically or manually fix the error "errors 2000, link count wrong"

Tags: btrfs, fsck, inode

I run btrfs-check and got the following errors:

```
$ sudo btrfs check --progress --force /dev/nvme0n1p7
Opening filesystem to check...
WARNING: filesystem mounted, continuing because of --force
Checking filesystem on /dev/nvme0n1p7
UUID: 0abfed09-85c5-44c3-8df1-8ed5db4bfe19
[1/7] checking root items                      (0:00:01 elapsed, 1111740 items checked)
[2/7] checking extents                         (0:00:10 elapsed, 148597 items checked)
[3/7] checking free space tree                 (0:00:00 elapsed, 330 items checked)
root 5 inode 14139676 errors 2000, link count wrong0:17 elapsed, 116205 items checked)
root 5 inode 14141114 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14141174 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14141175 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14141186 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14148125 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14148148 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14148168 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14148190 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14154429 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14154456 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14154459 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14154460 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14154468 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14154499 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14156088 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14156134 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14156137 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14157822 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14157857 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14157858 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14157859 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14157869 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14157870 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14157882 errors 2000, link count wrong
root 5 inode 14157919 errors 2000, link count wrong
[4/7] checking fs roots                        (0:00:18 elapsed, 117976 items checked)
ERROR: errors found in fs roots
found 313327153152 bytes used, error(s) found
total csum bytes: 303052904
total tree bytes: 2434465792
total fs tree bytes: 1940045824
total extent tree bytes: 117424128
btree space waste bytes: 467887914
file data blocks allocated: 350095093760
 referenced 275078295552
```

There is no detail specifying which file/path is broken. How can I fix it manually?

**UPDATE 1:** When I try to identify the scope of the damage, I use the following script to find all file associated with the above defective inodes:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

inode_list="14139676 14141114 14141174 14141175 14141186 14148125 14148148 14148168 14148190 14154429 14154456 14154459 14154460 14154468 14154499 14156088 14156134 14156137 14157822 14157857 14157858 14157859 14157869 14157870 14157882 14157919" # replace with your inode numbers
directory="/home" # replace with your directory

for inode in $inode_list
do
  echo "looking for inode $inode"
  find $directory -inum $inode
done
```

surprisingly, no file was discovered:

```
$ sudo ./findINode.sh 
looking for inode 14139676
looking for inode 14141114
looking for inode 14141174
looking for inode 14141175
looking for inode 14141186
looking for inode 14148125
looking for inode 14148148
looking for inode 14148168
looking for inode 14148190
looking for inode 14154429
looking for inode 14154456
looking for inode 14154459
looking for inode 14154460
looking for inode 14154468
looking for inode 14154499
looking for inode 14156088
looking for inode 14156134
looking for inode 14156137
looking for inode 14157822
looking for inode 14157857
looking for inode 14157858
looking for inode 14157859
looking for inode 14157869
looking for inode 14157870
looking for inode 14157882
looking for inode 14157919
```

How did this happen? Does this imply that any "dangerous" repair options can be conducted with no loss of data?

**UPDATE 2:** So I proceed to delete them:

```bash
inode_list="14139676 14141114 14141174 14141175 14141186 14148125 14148148 14148168 14148190 14154429 14154456 14154459 14154460 14154468 14154499 14156088 14156134 14156137 14157822 14157857 14157858 14157859 14157869 14157870 14157882 14157919" # replace with your inode numbers
directory="/home"

for inode in $inode_list
do
  echo "deleting inode $inode"
  find $directory -inum $inode -delete
done
```

But the problem persist, all the inode that are presumed deleted are still reported in btrfs check, is this caused by a defective implementation? What are the alternative ways to delete them?

Comment: You did not run `btrfs-check` with `--repair`?

Comment: That command gave me a big warning for the dangerous consequence it may cause (I'm using the obsolete btrfs-progs 5.12 provided by the system). So I backed off. Once I confirm that all those inodes are dangling. I'll probably take a leap of faith and do it :-D

Comment: "obsolete"...? However: What kind of block device is that, an LVM LV?

Comment: It is just a logical partition: /dev/nvme0n1p7